# Get HelpMessage and validateSet from parameters statement in powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

Firstly sorry for my english it's not my first language.

I have to generate a dictionary for a powershell project with spec(Mandatory,HelpMessage, etc ...) used in the different cmdlets. This dictionary is generated within an HTML file.

But I didn't find on internet how to get the ValidatingSet and HelpMessage of a parameter ...

Any idea ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
Get-Help *YourCommandHere* -full
```

Is what you want?